# How do I trust a swift macro target for Xcode Cloud builds?

Tags: xcode15, xcode-cloud, swift-macro

I just added my first Xcode 15, Swift 5.9 macro from an open source package that I'm referencing via Swift Package Manager. The first time I compiled locally, I had to trust the macro's package via a dialog box, which is fine for a local build. However, now my app doesn't build on Xcode Cloud, with the error *"Target must be enabled before it can be used."*

How do I tell Xcode Cloud to trust the macro's target?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran into same problem, and quickly discovered an additional defaults key that bypasses macro validation (same as `-skipMacroValidation` `xcodebuild` command line option):

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode IDESkipMacroFingerprintValidation -bool YES
```

Comment: This should be put in the `ci_post_clone.sh` file